# Projeto ASP.NET MVC não funciona na Hospedagem Godaddy Windows Plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, hospedagem

Olá, já li bastante perguntas aqui e já tentei de tudo, mas a minha aplicação MVC não roda mais nem com reza no servidor do Godaddy, já alterei a permissão dos arquivos, já inseri o trust level="Full" no Web.config, já verifiquei a versão do framework nas configurações e nada. Já mudei até as permissões via FTP. O pior de tudo ontem o suporte deles desligaram várias vezes na minha cara. 
Eu criei uma web application padrão do visual studio em MVC e tentei upar no site e nada! **Erro 500 depois, 403, 404.** Tentei também upar uma Web forms, mas os mesmos erros persistem. O último erro que eu recebo é **This program is blocked by group policy. for more information contact your system administrator.**
 Minha app é muito simples, não tem nem BD. Se alguém já passou por isso ou usa godaddy e puder me ajudar agradeço muito.